# Telerik Report Grouping - Alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a **Telerik invoice report** which contains the sold items. 
I am able to group the items but the grouping column pushes the other columns like this:

```
description 1 blah blah
                       item 1          $250
                       item 2          $260  
description 2 blah blah
                       item 1          $250
                       item 2          $260
```

However, I want to make it like the following:

```
description 1 blah blah 
item 1            $250    
item 2            $260
description 2 blah blah 
item 1            $250    
item 2            $260
```

I searched this website as well as google but couldn't find anything helpful so far.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the Telerik code and the generated output?

Comment: Hmm not quite sure what you mean but all i did was adding of report wizard and then added sql data source thrugh the wizard. Meaning no code and such. As explained the grouping column should appear just above the matching items and not being kind of pushed to the left while other columns to the right. Thank you

Comment: You should add an extra ROW in the table above the line that contains Item x and the price. Currently you just turn that desc column into group and you get what you get.